# Cauchy in product space

Tags: general-topology

[image: Engelking]

Here is the theorem for the completely metrizibility of Product spaces. For that each $(X_{i},\rho_{i})$ to be completely metrizable, The author said that for any cauchy sequence taken in $(X_{j},\rho_{j})$, $\{p_{j}^{* -1}(x_{i})\}$ is Cauchy in $X_{j},\rho_{j}$, Can we say that? I think being Cauchy is not a topological property? Or here is there any relation between that $\{p_{j}^{* -1}(x_{i})\}$  is Cauchy and our metrics are bounded by 1? or any easy way for the proof of each $(X_{i},\rho_{i})$ is completely metrizable? (metric on the product is $\rho(x,y)=\rho((x_{i}),(y_{i}))=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{i}}\rho_{i}(x_{i},y{i})$

Comment: Nice! Using Engelking I see..

Comment: yes, theorem from Engelking, any problem I share it like that?

Comment: No, not a problem at all. But for some who use screen readers, it might be. It's in general preferable to just retype pasages from books if you can (which can hard if there are diagrams e.g.) but you've typed some extra text that explains the problem, so I'm OK with this personnally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *metrics* on $X_j^\ast$ and $X_j$ are related (it's not merely the fact that they are homeomorphic): The former is the restricted $\rho$ (and all points in coordinates except $j$ are constant (the $A_i$) so $\rho(p_j^{-1}(x),p_j^{-1}(x')) = \frac{1}{2^j} \rho_j(x,x')$ for all $x,x' \in X_j$, is what the metric on $X_j^\ast$ is: just differing by a constant with $(X_j, \rho_j)$, so a Cauchy sequence in one is also one in the other. (It's also a quick extra argument why the restricted $p_j$ is a homeomorphism: it's an isometry-up-to-a-constant, a "scaling".)

Comment: thank you so much, Mr. Brandsma, I am so thankful :)

Comment: @Etü It's just a simple observation, but you're welcome. Glad to help.